# How to add two slanted columns inside full-width container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**I'm after this:** 
[image]

What I have is:

```
<div class="row slantrow">
    <div class="row slant-inner">
        <div class="col-md-6 slant-left">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 slant-right">
            <p>text in another div</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.slant-left {

}
.slant-right {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.slantrow {
    background-color: bisque;
}
.slant-inner {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I need DIV1 (should be 60% of the width) and DIV2 (should be 40% of the width) combined to have the width of page content.

Problems:

1. Adding slanted border to the DIV2
2. Getting the background color of DIV2 to go outside it's parent container

What would be the recommended way to achieve the look from the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it, by using css [`clip-path`](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path), in case you do not have to support IE.

```css
.slantrow {
    position: relative;
    background-color: bisque;
}
.slant-inner {
}
.slant-left {
    width: 60%;
}
.slant-right {
    width: 40%;
    /*background-color: antiquewhite;*/
}

.slant {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /* Play with `left` here */
    /* Used -15px, as the default gutter with in BS is 30px, you can adjust this based on your setup */
    left: calc(50% - 15px);
    background-color: antiquewhite;

    /* Play with `calc()` here */
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, calc(0% + 15px) 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, calc(0% + 15px) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="slantrow">
    <div class="slant"></div>

    <div class="container slant-inner">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 slant-left">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ipsum lectus, lacinia sed facilisis vel, euismod at quam. Pellentesque in urna dui. Duis ut elit id erat interdum tempor. Nam at lectus sit amet dolor interdum cursus a non enim.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 slant-right">
                <p>Morbi et pretium ex. Ut eros sapien, tincidunt et tincidunt eu, semper in libero. Nunc luctus ornare massa ut porta.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @dferenc for this nice approach. The problem is that the longer text overlaps DIV2 - where should be contained inside DIV1.

Comment: I just have updated the example to better fit longer texts. Please check out the inline comments in the css as well, indicating the lines that you can customize to alter the angle of the slant.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna mark your answer as correct one because it helped me with my problem. Now I need to make the whole thing responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Use one more div slant-middle in between slant-left and slant-right with same background color as slant-left and rotate it to 45deg.

```
transform: rotateZ(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
-o-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo-element to achieve this result. See the snippet below (see full page for a more accurate result):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.slantrow {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.slant-inner {
  display: flex;
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slant-inner p { position: relative; } /* Avoid paragraph being overlapped by the slanted box */

.slant-left {
  width: 60%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.slant-right {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.slant-right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: skewX(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="row slantrow">
    <div class="row slant-inner">
        <div class="col-md-6 slant-left">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean et augue at ipsum semper auctor a ut ante. Vivamus lacinia mollis semper. Aliquam fringilla eros at tortor semper, eget finibus urna tincidunt. Nulla mollis vestibulum elit vitae elementum. Nam lacinia elit id lacus bibendum, eget placerat augue auctor. Fusce viverra odio sapien, et auctor tellus accumsan eget. Duis ullamcorper eget elit nec varius. Nunc a nisl quis nunc bibendum lobortis vitae in risus. Ut eu pellentesque augue. Nulla ut nibh laoreet, egestas velit id, ultrices arcu. Curabitur eget iaculis orci. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 slant-right">
            <p>Aenean varius sollicitudin nulla. Proin in nisi urna. Aliquam ullamcorper dui vitae augue fringilla cursus vel finibus justo. Nullam tortor urna, rutrum et vulputate congue, consequat vitae nunc. Integer sit amet nibh blandit, venenatis velit ut, scelerisque quam. Phasellus quis leo eu quam sagittis egestas vel at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```